# Incorrect button width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Take a look a this](http://jsbin.com/iwimaw/5). I'm accessing the button's height and width using jquery's methods, and via accessing `.css("height")`, and I get two wrong answers.

I'm at 100% browser zoom. What's going on here?

```
Inner Height: 46, Inner Width: 196
Height: 46, Width: 196
CSS Height:44px, CSS Width: 184px
(The actual button dimensions are 200 X 50)
```

Comment: You'll need to post the CSS and HTML.  Probably there's padding or borders involved. Padding and borders, in the standard W3C box model, add to the actual width; they're not part of the width and height, in other words. Actual width is border-left-width + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right-width.

Comment: Ah, well looking at your jsbin, that looks fine to me. You can use Firebug's "Layout" view of the element to see all the contributors to element size. In this case, you've got 6 pixels of padding on the left and right, and 2 pixels of border all around.

Comment: As said in the answers, there's some default padding/border. To get the real size of an element, you can use outerHeight() / outerWidth() (include padding, etc.)

Comment: @CronosS - that's the best answer to this question (along side with explaining the issues).

Comment: @MiladNaseri - at the time I was looking at this, no answer was complete (with `outerWidth()`). Now there is such an answer. No offence, but you really don't need to explain to a 12k rep user how accepting answers work. Or did you copy-paste this?

Comment: Lol, copy-paste, of course. Sorry, I've been going around and digging out unaccepted answers for a whole day now. Forgot to look at your rep. :D

Comment: @Milad - No worries - you're doing good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overlooking the fact the by default, the boxing policy for CSS rendering excludes the border from the width-height. You have border-top = 1, border-bottom = 3, and border-right = border-left - 7, which accounts for the missing dimension.

To get the computed amounts for the width/height of an element, including it's border+padding you can use `outerWidth()`/`outerHeight()`

Also, in my case, I get all the values properly:

> Inner Height: 46, Inner Width: 186
>
> Height: 46, Width: 186
>
> CSS Height:46px, CSS Width: 186px
>
> (The actual button dimensions are 200 X 50)

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting it in Chrome, I also see:

```
border: 2px outset buttonface;
```

Therefore, add 2px to each side, or 4px to the total dimensions so the calculation of the size of the button itself is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The height and with of the button is 184 x 44 and it has a 1 x 6 padding and a 2px border. Totally it become 200 x 50:

[image: button dimensions]

It looks like a button width is the width you set - the padding - the border. So in jQuery you need to get the border and padding dimensions and count it.

And the innerWidth you get with jQuery is the width of the button + the padding, but not the border. So 184 x 44 + 6 x 1 became 196 x 46

Comment: ... or he can use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()`

Comment: @Pointy - why no answer? All the answers that explain the reasons why the measurement is bad are correct ... but they lack the simple reference to `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()`.

Comment: I haven't had any coffee yet this morning so I don't trust myself :-)  One thing to look into might be one of the various "browser reset" CSS files around the web.  Those sort-of "neutralize" all the intrinsic default sizing etc. that browsers apply to HTML elements. Some people find those useful.

Comment: Yes, I agree that they're controversial.  However, when used with some additional framework like the HTML5 Boilerplate, they don't seem terrible to me; *à chacun son goût*.

Answer (score 0):

All the answerers are technically correct, but, they left out this part: jquery's `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` take all these into account (I wasn't aware of these functions).

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iwimaw/6).